# Lowering Deployment Target for my app

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, ios-simulator

I created my Universal device game app in iOS 7.1 and there for have my deployment target set to 7.1. 
I currently use both iPhone/iPad simulators with 7.1 and 8.1 iOS versions.

Would there be an impact, in game performance, if I set my deployment target to iOS 6.1 or 7.0?
Would it be a negative impact if I set it lower than 7.1?

Comment: Only you can answer the question by testing on devices with the versions of iOS you wish to support. If you can't test with a given version, don't support that version.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you could be using code not compatible with older versions. The only way to know is to have the app compile to that iOS version. But, in my honest opinion, you should stick with 7.0 onwards since they are the officially supported versions. You could change your deployment target to 7.0 and try to compile to see the effects.

If you set the deployment target to 7.0, Xcode will tell you which parts of your code are non compatible.

Regarding performance, that depends on what type of code you did and which device you are going to deploy. For that response you need to provide a little bit of more info about your app and code. But like I said before, change the deployment target in 7.0 to at least be sure your code will run on that version.

Comment: I use Objective-C only for this app. The app is made for iPhone 4s/5/5s/6/6+ and iPad retina's and non-retina's.

Comment: Like I said, It is difficult to know that without testing it. If you can't get your hands in a real device with 6.0, I recommend you install Xcode 5 (you can install it side by side with xcode 6) and run a simulator with iOS 6. You cannot run a simulator with iOS6 on Xcode6. Apple is very strict about that. But I advise you to: 1) try it out in a real device with iOS 7 to see how it performs and 2) Stop support for iOS6 as it has been officially deprecated.

Comment: Xcode 6.1 doesn't even allow me to download/install anything earlier than iOS 7.0.3. So i guess iOS 6.1 is out of the question. However, i did install iOS 7.0.3 and the game works fine, no issues. So in Xcode 6.1, the the deployment targets are 6.1 then 7.0, then 7.1 and so on. Since i downloaded 7.0.3 would i be able to still use deployment target iOS 7.0?

Comment: The differences between the two are small/none in terms of API changes, so I think you can.

Answer (score 0):

There would be some performance hits in your code if you are using any functionality that is new to iOS 7.1 because you would need to check at runtime whether or not that functionality is present, and symbols for such functionality would be weakly bound.  However, that is *extremely* negligible and almost not worth mentioning beyond being overly specific.

On the whole, you should not see any performance impact simply by changing the deployment target version.